# Construct an sequence in order set

Tags: order-theory, ordinals

Assume that we have an uncountable ordered set $\Theta$.

Can we construct a sequence $(x_n)$ which $x_1<x_2<...<x_n<...$. In addition, for each $x\in \Theta$, there exists $n$ such that $x_n>x$?

Comment: Are you talking about a partial order? If that's the case, you can't obtain that sequence in general.

Comment: I mean ordered set by this definition:

< is a relation in A. < satisfies the following:
1. x !<x,
2. x<y, y<z---> x<z, and
3.$\forall x,y$, either  x< y or y<x.

Comment: That sequence can't be constructed if $A$ is finite, for example.

Comment: Oh! Thank you. I typed it wrong. I may assume that $\Theta$ is uncountable. I just edited the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot always do so. Let $\Theta$ be $\omega_1$, the first uncountable ordinal, in its natural order; then every strictly increasing sequence in $\Theta$ has an upper bound. $\Theta$ is well-ordered, so if you reverse the order, then every strictly increasing sequence is finite, and you can’t even get an infinite strictly increasing sequence.

Let $\langle\Theta,\preceq\rangle$ be a (non-strict) linear order. A subset $C$ of $\Theta$ is *cofinal* in $\Theta$ if for each $x\in\Theta$ there is a $y\in C$ such that $x\preceq y$. The *cofinality* of a linear order is the smallest cardinality of a cofinal subset. Your condition is precisely that $\Theta$ have cofinality $\omega$, i.e., countably infinite cofinality. Some uncountable linear orders do; $\Bbb R$ in its usual order is the obvious example. Some have uncountable cofinality; $\omega_1$ in its usual order is an example, as noted above. And some, like $\omega_1$ in its reversed order, have cofinality $1$, because they have a maximum element.

Comment: Why every strictly increasing sequence in $\omega_1$ has an upper bounded?

Comment: @WorawitTepsan: Suppose that $x_1<x_2<\ldots$. For each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $A_n=\{x\in\Theta:x\le x_n\}$. By the definition of $\omega_1$ each of the sets $A_n$ is countable, so $\bigcup_{n\ge 1}A_n$ is countable. $\Theta$ is uncountable, so there is a $y\in\Theta\setminus\bigcup_{n\ge 1}A_n$. Then $x<y$ for every $x\in\bigcup_{n\ge 1}A_n$, and since $x_n\in A_n$, $y$ is an upper bound for $\{x_n:n\ge 1\}$.

Comment: I understand that $A_n\subset \omega_1$. But does this imply that the cardinal of $A_n $ is less than $\omega_1$?

Comment: @WorawitTepsan: No. However, the sets $A_n$ *are* necessarily countable, because by definition each $\alpha<\omega_1$ has only countably many predecessors.

Comment: I'll try to understand it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @WorawitTepsan: You're very welcome. It may help to read [this](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number).